# How to Set MQGet CodedCharSetID in Apache Camel

Tags: character-encoding, apache-camel, ibm-mq

currently I am working with Apache Camel and IBM Websphere MQ. In my project, I would like to write xml message into IBM WMQ and to do so I need to change the MQGet CodedCharSetID from 1208 into 819.

Anyone has an idea about how to do so in apache camel?

For your information:

1. I have tried to use the convertbodyto tag, but it did not worked.
2. I have also tried to add CCSID property in WMQ Connection Factory Bean, and it also did not worked.

Your help is so much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the destination name as queue:///FOO.BAR?CCSID=819 instead of simply FOO.BAR

If that does not work out, there is a workaround to set the option on [Camel JMS docs](http://camel.apache.org/jms#JMS-SettingJMSprovideroptionsonthedestination).